# How to use "Case when" in "after update" trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have an "update" trigger that looks like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `Removal_add` BEFORE UPDATE ON `post_cost` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
SET NEW.Removal_pl = ((CASE WHEN (SELECT `Poli_csl` FROM slid WHERE slid.id = NEW.id)<10 THEN 
 (SELECT `Model_R_Hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 
 (SELECT `Time_hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 0.3 
 ELSE (SELECT `Model_R_Hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 
 (SELECT `Time_hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) END));
END
```

This trigger works for me. But I also want to create an "after update" trigger with the same condition from the trigger above, but I don't know how to do it, so far it gives an error.

The after update trigger itself:

```
CREATE TRIGGER post_2
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON slid FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
UPDATE `harld`.`post_cost` SET `Removal_pl` = CASE WHEN NEW.`Poli_csl` < 10  WHERE `id` = NEW.id THEN
 (SELECT `Model_R_Hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 
 (SELECT `Time_hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 0.3 
 ELSE (SELECT `Model_R_Hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 
 (SELECT `Time_hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) END));
END;
```

What's wrong? please tell me

Comment: You have a pretty obvious syntax error in your code: `CASE WHEN NEW.Poli_csl < 10 WHERE id = NEW.id THEN` - the WHERE id = NEW.id makes no sense here and you probably want to add it after the SET clause to filter the rows to update.

Comment: A `case` expression is terminated by an `end`, in between are conditions starting `when..` followed by `then..` so something is done. An example is: `case when x = y then 1 end` . Do you really need a case expression? if so, ensure its syntax is correct.